# Python print first row of list

Tags: python, list, row

I'm sure there a simple solution to this question but so far it has eluded me.

I simply want to print out the first row the below list where [0] is the None value and [1] is the time stamp. Where ss is the list name.

```
None 2018-05-21 00:15:23.154428
None 2018-05-21 00:15:25.154428
None 2018-05-21 00:28:49.154627
None 2018-05-21 00:30:21.154642
None 2018-05-21 00:30:23.154642
None 2018-05-21 00:43:17.154838
None 2018-05-21 00:43:19.154838
None 2018-05-21 00:45:19.154857
None 2018-05-21 00:45:21.154857
None 2018-05-21 00:45:23.154858
None 2018-05-21 01:43:17.155843
None 2018-05-21 01:43:19.155843
None 2018-05-21 01:43:21.155843
None 2018-05-21 02:28:17.156551
None 2018-05-21 02:28:19.156552
None 2018-05-21 02:28:21.156552
None 2018-05-21 02:28:23.156553
None 2018-05-21 02:28:25.156553
None 2018-05-21 02:28:27.156553
None 2018-05-21 02:30:17.156571
None 2018-05-21 02:30:19.156571
None 2018-05-21 02:30:21.156571
None 2018-05-21 02:58:17.157040
None 2018-05-21 03:13:17.157249
None 2018-05-21 03:43:17.157726
None 2018-05-21 03:58:21.157929
None 2018-05-21 03:58:23.157930
None 2018-05-21 04:00:17.158008
None 2018-05-21 04:00:19.158009
None 2018-05-21 04:00:21.158009
None 2018-05-21 04:58:17.158840
None 2018-05-21 04:58:19.158841
None 2018-05-21 05:13:17.159086
None 2018-05-21 05:13:19.159086
```

Here are several things I've attempted.

```
#print ss[:2]

#print next(ss)

#for item in ss[0:1]:
#   print item

#for i in ss :
#   print(i[0])
#print(ss(zip(*0))[0])

#print ss [0:1]

#for row[0] for row in ss:
print row
```

Comment: just to clarify I need both columns of the row

Comment: You will have to `split()` the line.

Comment: To print only first row try with `print ss[0]`

Comment: print(ss[0][3]) gives me 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Post how your array is built (columns) or it's hard to figure out. Remember that python starts counting from 0 so, if your column are separated by spaces, you don't have the '3rd' item in the row -> to print 3rd column of first row you have to sat print ss[0][2] or just ss[0][-1] -> -1 sytays for last column

Comment: print ss[0] returns all value in the 0 column i.e. a long list of NONE's

Comment: I want to print both columns of the first row only. In the list above that would be  [0]None [1]2018-05-21 00:15:23.154428

Answer (score 0):

If the list contains pairs of values, then the timestamp will be at index 1. Try using `row[1]` to access it.

Comment: But what is the correct syntax ?

print ss(row[1])

Can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are starting with a chunk of text:

```
text_block = """None 2018-05-21 00:15:23.154428
None 2018-05-21 00:15:25.154428
None 2018-05-21 00:28:49.154627
None 2018-05-21 00:30:21.154642
None 2018-05-21 00:30:23.154642
None 2018-05-21 00:43:17.154838
None 2018-05-21 00:43:19.154838
None 2018-05-21 00:45:19.154857
None 2018-05-21 00:45:21.154857
None 2018-05-21 00:45:23.154858
None 2018-05-21 01:43:17.155843
None 2018-05-21 01:43:19.155843
None 2018-05-21 01:43:21.155843
None 2018-05-21 02:28:17.156551
None 2018-05-21 02:28:19.156552
None 2018-05-21 02:28:21.156552
None 2018-05-21 02:28:23.156553
None 2018-05-21 02:28:25.156553
None 2018-05-21 02:28:27.156553
None 2018-05-21 02:30:17.156571
None 2018-05-21 02:30:19.156571
None 2018-05-21 02:30:21.156571
None 2018-05-21 02:58:17.157040
None 2018-05-21 03:13:17.157249
None 2018-05-21 03:43:17.157726
None 2018-05-21 03:58:21.157929
None 2018-05-21 03:58:23.157930
None 2018-05-21 04:00:17.158008
None 2018-05-21 04:00:19.158009
None 2018-05-21 04:00:21.158009
None 2018-05-21 04:58:17.158840
None 2018-05-21 04:58:19.158841
None 2018-05-21 05:13:17.159086
None 2018-05-21 05:13:19.159086"""

# create a list of strings
row_list = text_block.split("\n")

# 'None', '2018-05-21', '00:15:23.154428'
none_str, date_str, time_str = row_list[0].split()
```

If you are only interested in the first line of the text block, you can perform the split on the first '\n' and discard the rest.

```
first_line = text_block.split("\n", 1)[0]
elements = first_line.split()

# elements[0] : 'None'
# elements[1] : '2018-05-21'
# elements[2] : '00:15:23.154428'
```

To print the elements is easy:

```
# Python 2.x:
print "{0} {1} {2}".format(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2])

# Python 3.x:
print("{0} {1} {2}".format(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2]))
```

Comment: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. Do I need to import split ?

Comment: `.split()` splits a string into a list

Comment: So I converted the list to a string and used the above code from Dan Nagle and I still get a full print out of all elements i.e. every row and every column. All I want is the first row.

Comment: Update the code in the question to show exactly what you have done.